# Android minSdk and dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I read that my app will be able to run on the minimum SDK version, 16 in this case:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.github.dht.screenger"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
...
```

So what will happen with level 23 dependencies when running on an API 16 device?

**Dependencies**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
....
```

Comment: Nothing.. I guess it will work then :-p

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049908/appcompat-compatibility-and-support-libraries-for-lollipop-if-minimum-sdk-14

Comment: @Guy, let me know if any part of the answer is not clear

Comment: Very clear, thank you. I was still amazed by the prospect of using everything on the design support to accept the answer ;-). accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT mainly **depends on the feature and have you used support library or not**, cause in case you have used a **feature from the support library that's backward compatible then the  library takes care of it else the native behavior kicks in**,

> Lets take the most common scenario, The status bar

IN API level 16 there is no status bar color tinting but a black status bar is shown but from API 21 on-wards it's there so here as we can see the native behavior of that particular version kicks-in

> now lets see the com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0

As you can see the v7 specifies that the library is backward compatible till version API version 7( ECLAIR_MR1) so the support library does that for you.

> The final case using methods available only in that particular version
>   of SDK

When this happens the compiler throws an error saying you cant use this since the min supported version does not have this methods.